# What should degrees of freedom $\nu$ be set to when modeling financial returns that follow the t-distribution?

Tags: statistics, distribution, statistical-finance, asset-returns, parameter

The closer the t-distribution degrees of freedom ($\nu$) is to 0, the more heavy are the tails, whereas high degrees of freedom recovers the normal distribution.

In finance, what value is usually used for the degrees of freedom of financial returns data?

$\nu = 1$, $\nu = 2$ or $\nu = 3$? Are fractional values like 1.5 ever used instead of integers?

Comment: One approach might be to use maximum-likelihood for whatever sort of returns dataset you are estimating. Using this method, non-integer parameters are valid.

Comment: In general I doubt there will be a one-size-fits-all choice of $\nu$

Comment: I would agree with both comments. but in traditional finance which integer is most commonly seen

Comment: From memory, a typical distribution of daily stock returns is usually found to have about 4 dof. Your mileage may vary. Fractional values can be used.

Comment: Please also note that for the $t$-distribution with degree of freedoms $\nu$, all moments $k\geq \nu$ do not exist.

Comment: My friend Wm. Egan for example found $\nu=3.6$ for S&P500 daily returns 1950-2005 http://www.dailyspeculations.com/Egan_Dis.pdf

Comment: thanks for these observations. for some reason I had always seen $\nu=2$ or $3$ for stock returns, but can't seem to dig them up. any higher was often shown to be too Normal